# Unable to get the first bar to show up in python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

For some reason my plot at 50 is not showing up and I can't figure out why. any help would be much appreciated.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
num = [50, 100, 150, 300, 400]
prob = [0.08, .03, .013,.0033,0]
plt.bar(num,prob)
plt.xlabel("Number of Flaws")
plt.ylabel ("probability")
plt.show()
```

[image: plot of code]

Comment: It works fine for me. To make it more thick, try `plt.bar(num,prob,width=10)`

Comment: it does show up on my python 3.7.6 with matplotlib 3.1.1. What are your versions?

Comment: I forgot: I'm on a retina Mac. There is another strangeness in your plot: the bars above 150 and 300 are not aligned with the ticks on the x-axis. This could be due to the same problem that makes the bar over 50 disappear. There is a good chance that drawing it thicker will make it appear again. Also resize the graph by hand. If the bar appears, it's a graphics artifact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
num = [50, 100, 150, 300, 400]
prob = [0.08, .03, .013,.0033,0]
plt.bar(num,prob, width=3)
plt.xlabel("Number of Flaws")
plt.ylabel ("probability")
plt.show()
```

For some reason the width of the chart is problematic. Change it and it will be fine. Also it's will be more clear that way. It is an argument of the bar chart.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

num = [50, 100, 150, 300, 400]
prob = [0.08, .03, .013,.0033,0]
plt.bar(num,prob)
plt.xlabel("Number of Flaws")
plt.ylabel ("probability")
```

> **plt.tight_layout()**

```
plt.show()
```

Comment: that worked as well.. I'm going to have to keep that tight_layout() syntax in mind.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to not specify the width manually but use some way which scales automatically. For example, you can use a width that is 10% of the lowest value

```
num = [50, 100, 150, 300, 400]
prob = [0.08, .03, .013, .0033, 0]
plt.bar(num,prob, width = 0.1*min(num))
```